# Do I still need to install Node.js or Python via docker container file when the OS is installed with python/node.js already?

Tags: docker, microservices, virtualization, docker-container

I am trying to create the docker file (Image file) for the web application I am creating. Basically, the web application is written in Node.js and Vue.js. In order to create a docker container for the application, I have got the documentation from vue.js to create a docker file. The steps given are working file. I just wanted to clear my understanding in this part.

link:- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

If the necessary package Node/Python is installed in the OS (Not in the container), would the container be able to pick up the npm scripts and execute python scripts also? If yes, is it really dependent on the OS software packages as well?

Please help me with the understanding.

Comment: The best thing you could do is to create a container with all the configurations and packages. If you want to deploy later on you can just use docker and the docker container.

Comment: @collin, yes indeed. I would like to know if the OS has the python installed already, do I still need to install the python in the container also.

Comment: Containers are completely isolated from the host system.  A container has no idea what software is available on the host, and can’t run language interpreters that are there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Node or Python or whatever software you need in your application in your container. The reason is that the container should be able to run on any host machine that has Docker installed, regardless of how the host machine is set up or what it software it has installed.

It might be a bit tedious at first to make sure that your `Dockerfile` installs all the software that is needed, but it becomes very useful when you want to run your container on another machine. Then all you have to do is type `docker run` and it should work!

Like David said above, Docker containers are isolated from your host machine and it should be treated as a completely different machine/host. The way containers can communicate with other containers or sometimes the host is through network ports.

One "exception" to the isolation between the container and the host is that the container can sometimes write to files in the host in order to persist data even after the container has been stopped. You can use [volumes or mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) to allow containers to write to files on the host.

I would suggest the [Docker Overview](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/) for more information about Docker.

Comment: Very well written about the containers. I am using macbook. Can I consider it as the host machine? My node js application contains the node_modules to build the packages. I am completely copying it to the container package and running npm scripts.
w.r.t containers I am installing the required runtime as well apart from the libraries required to execute. Is it not it something heavy weight when all the containers have the runtime engines (node.js) with it? If I create it as micro service, all the containers will have the runtime engines. Cant we keep it isolated from the containers?

Comment: Yes, you can consider your mac as your host machine. No, it's not that "heavy-weight," it's much less heavy-weight compared to virtual machines. If you keep your runtime outside of your container (if it was possible) then you won't have a reproducible environment anymore. The very purpose of Docker is to manage the application runtime.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. It was a great explanation indeed. Now I can start exploring more on docker.